Salesforce Permission Set Group
In Salesforce there are few permission sets which has View all data/ Modify all data is enabled in System Permission and i am trying to group these permission set and create a muting Permission Set. I need to disable View all and modify all in one of the custom object in those permission set. Is this possible in salesforce?
Scenario:
PermissionSetA with View all data in system permission
PermissionSetB with View all and Modify all data in system permission
CustomObjectA__c - it has access in PermissionSetA and and PermissionSetB
New PermissionSetGroupA- trying to combine PermissionSetA and PemrissionSetB into one single group and create a muting permissionSet for CustomObjectA by muting View all and modify all.
Error:
I was not able to combine PermissionSetA with PermissionSetB in permission Set group . if i want to achieve this , i need to disable View all data/ Modify all data in System Permission.
Goal:
CustomObjectA is a private Object, only owner of the record must have access to their record and it should be visible if it is shared. Achieved this scenario but in sharing hierarchy of the record there were users who had access to all the records which should not be there unless they have system admin profile. When i checked i found out users in sharing hierarchy was getting access through permissionSet. So is possible to control mute View all / modify all through permission set group, if not any idea on how to achieve this.

You can't mute system-level permissions like "View All Data" or "Modify All Data" using a Permission Set Group or Muting Permission Set. Instead:

Use Separate Permission Sets:
Apply PermissionSetA and PermissionSetB individually and create a Muting Permission set for CustomObjectA__c to control its access.

Adjust Permissions:
Review and adjust the permissions in your Permission Sets to ensure they align with your needs for CustomObjectA__c.

Consider Custom Profiles:
If muting doesn't fully work, create custom profiles or permission sets that manage access to CustomObjectA__c.



We are not considering profiles, since this object must have access only through permission set. There are users who have permission set with system permission view all and modify all and when we apply the new permission set , the access is overridden
